# Convert Date and Time strings to DateTime

Tags: php, date, datetime, time, converters

I'm trying to convert Date and Time to DateTime format using PHP:

```
$matches_date = null;
preg_match('/\[(.*[^]])\]/', $line_text, $matches_date);
print "DATE: ".$matches_date[1]."<br>";

$matches_time = null;
preg_match('/\(([^)]*)\)/', $line_text, $matches_time);
print "TIME: ".$matches_time[1]."<br>";

$release_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($matches_date[1] + " " + $matches_time[1]));
print "DATETIME: ".$release_date."<br>";
```

Output:

> DATE: 2013-01-30
>
> TIME: 13:00:00
>
> DATETIME: 2013-05-10 20:26:00

DateTime is incorrect. How do I fix it? Tried many variations but none worked.

Comment: What is the value of `$line_text` input?

Comment: Also, you are missing a space between the date and the time when you concatenate them.

Comment: it doesn't matter. The point of that code is that $matches_date[1] - is a date string and $matches_time[1] - is a time string.

Comment: You may take a look on a `DateTime` object. May be very helpful. http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php

Comment: @MattJohnson that's the result of variations. sorry, forgot to fix it back.. but the space doesn't fix my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong operator to concatenate.  `.` not `+`

```
$release_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($matches_date[1] . " " . $matches_time[1]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this "D, d M Y H:i:s T" in place of "Y-m-d H:i:s"